# SQLite: SQLITE_BUSY on ATTACHed database and parallel read-only connection to the attached database

Tags: sqlite, transactions, database-connection, system.data.sqlite

let me try to explain the problem in general parlance.

We are using SQLite 3.7.11 by System.Data.SQLite Wrapper for .NetCF in Version 1.0.80.

We have two database files:

- master_data.db
- inventory.db

We establish a read-only connection to *master_data.db* to display some information to the user.

```
Data Source=master_data.db;Version=3;Read Only=true;Journal Mode=OFF;Synchronous=OFF;
```

We establish a writable connection to *inventory.db* to update/insert inventory information depending on some information from *master_data.db*

```
Data Source=inventory.db;Version=3;Journal Mode=DELETE;Synchronous=OFF;
```

To allow consistency checks in update/insert statements, we attach the *master_data.db* to this connection.

```
ATTACH 'master_data.db' AS md_db
```

We start a transaction at *inventory.db*

```
SQLiteTransaction tx = connection.BeginTransaction();
```

We update a simple table in *inventory.db* without interaction of master_data.db.

```
using (IDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"UPDATE header_info SET count_time = @countTime";
    SQLiteParameterparam = new SQLiteParameter("@countTime",
                                               DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime())
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param)
    return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

We commit the changes and it will hang until timeout occurs and **SQLITE_BUSY** is raised.

```
tx.Commit();// BAAM! due to SQLITE_BUSY
```

We do not understand what's wrong here. The established read-only connection to *master_data.db* cannot lock the whole database. Even if there is a second and writable (the only one) connection due to the ATTACH command - which was executed by the one and only writable *inventory.db* connection. We are sure ther is no second connection to *inventory.db*.

[EDIT]
In the case of error no other transaction to master_data.db is open. Even the connection is not in use but open.
[/EDIT]

May this issue, we are also facing, be part of the problem? [SQLite: Multiple Connections to one file - the one and only writable is not persisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985237/sqlite-multiple-connections-to-one-file-the-one-and-only-writable-is-not-pers)

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Schibbl

Answer (score 0):

When you have attached databases, a transaction always covers all those databases.

So when you want to write to a database, you have to ensure that no other connection has any open transaction on the main database or on any of the attached databases.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I did not mention, that in the case of error no other transaction to master_data.db was open.